# How can I edit this fiddle to close the animation after few seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I edit this fiddle to close the animation after few seconds?

```js
$('div').animate({left: 0});
```

```css
div{
  background: red; 
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jamygolden/Ctv6N/

**Update Code:** - This box in this code shifts to the right side and does not completely disappear from the window.

```
<div class="animateSliding" id="animateSliding">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#animateSliding').animate({right: 0}, 1000, function() {
            var animateStuff = $(this);
            var duration = 3000;
            setTimeout(function () {
                animateStuff.animate({right: '-300px'});
            }, duration);
        });
    </script>
    <p>You are almost done!</p>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.animateSliding {
background: #b2b2b2;
border-top: 3px solid #ccc; 
height: 200px; 
width: 300px; 
position: absolute; 
right: -300px;
padding-top: 80px;
padding-left: 80px;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `setTimeout()`

```
$('div').animate({left: 0} , 1000 , function(){
   var ThisIt = $(this);
   var duration = 3000; // 3s duration to close -- change it as you like
   setTimeout(function(){
      ThisIt.animate({left: '-100px'});
   }, duration);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/Ctv6N/1475/)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Also, i wanted to know that there are fancy sliding windows/images which most of the websites have. How can I use an image in place of the box that slides in?

Comment: @dsingh23 you mean you need to use img instead of div?? or img inside div??

Comment: Yes, an image inside a div.

Comment: @dsingh23 Ok please give me sometimes I will make a demo with img

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @dsingh23 something like this??  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/Ctv6N/1477/

Comment: Yes, I just removed the background from the CSS and it worked the way i want!

Comment: I wrote this code in my website, and i noticed that it shifted to the right side  and not disappeared completely.

Comment: you should change ThisIt.animate({left: '-100px'});  with the new width you have

Comment: I did make the width same, but it's still shifting to the right.

Comment: @dsingh23 if your website is live  send the link

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot send the link due to reasons.

Comment: @dsingh23 never mind its Ok .. try to update the demo with your related code  and send the new demo to me

Comment: @dsingh23 try to add the padding to be ThisIt.animate({right: '-380px'});

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you may add a second parameter that is the duration. There is also a parameter complete that is a callback to call when the animation is ended:

```js
$(function () {
  $('div').animate({left: 0}, 3000, "swing", function() {
     $(this).animate({left: '-100px'});
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in this way:

```
$('div').animate({left: 0}, function(){
   setTimeout(function(e){
       $('div').animate({left: -100})
  }, 2000)
});
```

Change the timeout (currently 2000) whith the value you prefer.